# Showing surjection

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose 
$\psi$ is a bijection
$\psi: G\rightarrow H$

$\left ( g \right )\psi \mapsto  h$

I want to show that $\psi^{-1}$ is also a bijection.

$\psi^{-1}: H\rightarrow G$

$\left ( h \right )\psi^{-1} \mapsto g$

It is necessary to show that $\psi$ is an injection and surjection.

Showing injection seems easy here so I shall omit it.

As a note,

> Definition:
>
> $\psi^{-1}: H\rightarrow G$
>   then $\psi^{-1}$ is an injective function if
>
> $\forall g \in G, \exists h \in  H$
>
> $\left ( h \right )\psi^{-1}=g$

$\left ( h \right )\psi^{-1}=g$

But $\left ( g \right )\psi=h$

$\left ( h \right )\psi^{-1}=g \Rightarrow \left ( \left ( g \right ) \right )\left ( \psi \psi^{-1} \right )=ge=g$

I doubt the above is correct. Would someone assists me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\psi:G \longrightarrow H$ be a bijection.

$\textbf{Short version:}$

$\psi$ a bijection means $\psi$ has a two-sided inverse, call it $\psi^{-1}$, such that $(\psi \circ \psi^{-1})(h) = h$, for all $h \in H$, and $(\psi^{-1} \circ \psi)(g)=g$, for all $g \in G$.

But then $\psi$ is a two-sided inverse for $\psi^{-1}$, so $\psi^{-1}$ is a bijection.

$\textbf{Long version:}$

By definition of bijection, $\psi$ is both an injection and a surjection.

Remember that:

$\psi$ an injection means that, given $x, y \in G$ with $x \neq y$, $\psi(x) \neq \psi(y)$.

$\psi$ a surjection means that, given $z \in H$, there exists $w \in G$ such that $\psi(w)=z$.

Choose $h \in H$. Since $\psi$ is surjective, there exists $h' \in G$ such that $\psi(h')=h$. Since $\psi$ is injective, this $h'$ is unique.

Let the map $\psi^{-1}:H \longrightarrow G$ be given by $\psi^{-1}(h)=h'$, where $h' \in G$ is the unique element in $G$ with $\psi(h')=h$.

That $\psi^{-1}$ is well-defined follows directly from the fact that, for $h_{1}, h_{2} \in H$ with $h_{1}=h_{2}$, the contrapositive of the definition of injectivity given above, coupled with the injectivity of $\psi$, forces $\psi^{-1}(h_{1})=\psi^{-1}(h_{2})$.

$\psi^{-1}$ is an injection, since, for $x, y \in H$ with $x \neq y$, we have $\psi^{-1}(x) \neq \psi^{-1}(y)$, because $\psi$ is well-defined.

$\psi^{-1}$ is clearly a surjection, since for $h' \in G$, $\psi(h')=h \in H$, hence $\psi^{-1}(h)=h'$.

Thus $\psi^{-1}$ is a bijection.